# Flutter audio recording

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a code for recording audio when we long press a button and when we stopping pressing the button the recording should stop. I want a code for my flutter app. Please help guys.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. use a plugin  [here](https://pub.dev/packages?q=audio%20recorder)
2. implement platfor method calls ,  using [audio record api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord)